# navbar has border around it and it can't be removed

Tags: html, css, nav

I am trying to create a navigation bar for my website and something strange is happening. It's a border around the navigation bar and I can't remove it? I tried searching for the error but nothing works. I tried setting border to 0px in style tag but didn't work, the border is still there, how? Please help me and thanks in advance

code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #282e30;
  border: 0px;
}

#nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 0px;
}

#nav a.active {
    background-color: #286a82;
    color: white;
    border: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
  <a class="active" href="/home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="/contact.html">Contact us!</a>
  <a href="/about.html">About!</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `border: 0px;` in your code, it's not a border around the navbar but it's a margin on the body element in your HTML. By default the `<body>` tag has a slight margin causing it to look like you have a border there. Try adding `body{margin:0px;}` in your code and it should work. Like this:

```
<style>
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #282e30;
}

#nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#nav a.active {
    background-color: #286a82;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I added the body {margin:0px;} and uploaded it, it now displays without the border/margin :D Thanks